# Integral expression for $P(X_1 \leq x_1, ...., X_n \leq x_n \mid N = n)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

What is the integral expression for $P(X_1 \leq x_1, ...., X_n \leq x_n\mid N = n)$? I am confused by having a joint and conditional probability.

I know:
$P(X_1 \leq x_1 , ..., X_n \leq x_n) = \int_{-\infty}^{x_1} ... \int_{-\infty}^{x_n} f(u_1,...,u_n) du_1 ... du_n$

And I also thought to use:
$P(X=x,Y=y)=P(Y=y)P(X=x\mid Y=y)$

But I don't know how to connect these.
Can somebody explain? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is $(X_n)$ and what is $N$?

Comment: The ($X_n$) denote indeed random variables, more specifically interarrival times of a renewal process. Hence $N(t)$ is the number of events that happened before time $t$.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** As the comment eludes to, having $X_n$ and $N$ is confusing. Suppose we have a random variable $Y$ in place of $N$.

I assume you are dealing with continuous random variables. Let $X = (X_1, \dots, X_n)$ and $x = (x_1, \dots, x_n)$. Then the conditional cdf of $X$ given $Y = y$ is defined as follows

$$
\begin{align}
F_{X|Y}(x|y) &=
P(X \leq x | Y = y) \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{x_1} \cdots \int_{-\infty}^{x_n}f_{X|Y}(x|y)dx \\
&= \frac{1}{f_Y(y)}\int_{-\infty}^{x_1} \cdots \int_{-\infty}^{x_n} f_{XY}(x,y)dx.
\end{align}
$$

Here, $f_{X|Y}(x|y) = \frac{f_{XY}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}$.